# How can define private function in React-Native js

Tags: react-native

i want to create such function which can't be access from outside the component of createClass

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: i want to create such function which can't be access from outside the component of createClass 

var Weekdays = React.createClass({  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style= {styles.container}>
        <Text>
          hello
        </Text>
        {this.days()}
      </View>
    );
  },
  days: function() {
    var dayItems = [];
    for(var i=0; i<7; i++) {
      var day = Moment().day(i,'days').format('dddd');
      dayItems.push(
        <DayItem day = {day}>
      )
    }
    return dayItems;
  }
});  DAY FUNCTION SHOULD BE PRIVATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Privacy is a tricky problem in javascript there are ways of doing it with different type of tradeoffs. But there is no way of making a function private inside of a react component. 
You can place the function outside the react component but in the same module with your component and not export that but (again, there are tradeoffs) that means you won't be able to access props or state in that function. In my opinion you don't have to worry about privacy in your react components, privacy is implied, almost all the time (in my opinion) no one should be calling functions directly from your react component.